# JTextField Width

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager

The textfield is wider than I want, I've tried changing the number in the `new JTextField("", 5)` part but it doesn't affect the width it has when I open the frame

```
    if (eventSource == bestelOnderdelen) {
        ArrayList<Integer> onderdeelNrs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> onderdeelOmschrijving = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < modelOnderdelen.getRowCount(); i++) {
            if ((boolean) modelOnderdelen.getValueAt(i, 0)) {
                onderdeelNrs.add(Integer.parseInt((String)modelOnderdelen.getValueAt(i, 1)));
                onderdeelOmschrijving.add((String) modelOnderdelen.getValueAt(i, 2));
            }
        }

        bestellenOnderdelen = new JPanel();
        bestellenOnderdelen.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        bestellenOnderdelen.add(new JLabel("Hoeveel wilt u van de volgende artikelen bestellen?"));

        for(Integer a: onderdeelNrs){
            bestellenOnderdelen.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(a)+" "+onderdeelOmschrijving.get(onderdeelNrs.indexOf(a))));
            bestellenOnderdelen.add(new JTextField("", 5));
        }

        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, bestellenOnderdelen) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I've changed the layout from `bestellenOnderdelen.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bestellenOnderdelen, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));` to `bestellenOnderdelen.setLayout(new FlowLayout());` but now I face another problem, how do I give the panel a fixed width and variable height?

Comment: Columns only sets the preferred width. You need to set the width manually by ```setSize``` or modify the layout

Comment: _You need to set the width manually by setSize_ no, you never do any manual sizing (nor locating) of components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening most probably due to the `LayoutManager`. Try a different layout manager like `GridBagLayout`, which is much more flexible. You may also want to override the `getPreferredSize()` method in the `JTextField`.

Comment: I've now set it to FlowLayout, but now I have another question: how do i give the panel a fixed with and variable height?

Comment: Just override the method getPreferredWidth() in the panel. In the overridden method `return new Dimension(super.getPreferredSize().width, yourPreferredHeight)`. If you just want to restrict the size of JFrame, look at method setMinimumSize() in JFrame.